# How to generate .stl files

Tags: ros, stl, mesh

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How to generate .stl files for my robot? As far as I understand I need to create CAD model for each link and then export it as .stl file (binary not ascii?). Which one (Autodesk Inventor, SolidWorks...etc) provides binary .stl files? 'll the stl files from the CAD software work as it is OR do I need to change anything before using in URDF file?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11305/how-to-generate-.stl-files/) by [VN](https://answers.ros.org/users/841/vn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 373 on 2011-09-24

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To answer your questions:

- yes, you need to create CAD models of your robot links
- the mesh formats that ROS understands are STL, DAE and Ogre
- both Autodesk Inventor and SolidWorks can export to STL format
- ROS (RViz etc.) understands both binary and ASCII STL
- SolidWorks produces *binary* STL files that *look like* ASCII STL files, thereby confusing ROS; but these files can be fixed (search previous questions tagged "stl")
- you can use [ivcon](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ivcon) to convert between binary and ASCII STL, and other formats
- the STL files from the CAD software should work as they are; if you need to do some tweaking (rescaling, rotating, whatever), [MeshLab](http://meshlab.sourceforge.net/) comes in very handy

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2011-09-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) on 2011-10-07**:
I was able to open my mesh files in RViz, but not Gazebo. In Meshlab, Filters->Remeshing->Quadric Edge Collapse Decimation I reduced the number of faces to < 5000 for each mesh. The results were not pretty, but I am able to open CAD files with Gazebo and RViz now. Saved the resulting stl as binary.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, you need to create a CAD model (for each link if they have DOF).

You can get binary stl files with SolidWorks, just marking the option when exporting the .stl file. You can use them straight from the CAD just take into account that the reference coordinates and units may change from SolidWorks to RViz.

If you just need a fast model you can use Google's SketchUP, I wrote this short how-to [SketchUp to STL](http://wikiri.upc.es/index.php/Sketchup_to_STL) page.

If you find any exporting issues check out [Meshlab](http://meshlab.sourceforge.net/)

---

Originally posted by [martimorta](https://answers.ros.org/users/69/martimorta/) with karma: 843 on 2011-09-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2